# Is there a way to retrieve hidden input values on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

I am trying to take the inputs the customer selects, and add them to hidden fields, to then be able to display them on the cart page.

```
<form method="post" action="https://omgneonsigns.com/cart/?add-to-cart=5825" name="contentForm" runat="server">
```

Here is the code for my form, and of course I have my fields setup this way:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenText" name="hiddenText" value="">
```

So, what is the next step? I am able to alert the values back to me, so I know they are being held/stored... but I'm not sure how to take them with me to the next page and alert them there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to select the hidden input. `JavaScript` way:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenText" name="hiddenText" value="" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">

<script>
    function myFunction(val) {
        let hidden_val = val 
        // now store it using `session`
    }
</script>
```

Basically you can do it in many ways:

1. Use `JavaScript` session. link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp
2. Use `php` session. link:
   https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Then get the value in the next page from `session`.

Comment: Thank you for this! So to store it using 'session', would I still need to use document.getElementById?

For example: sessionStorage.setItem("hiddenText", document.getElementById('hiddenText').value);

Comment: the JavaScript onchange event will be triggered by changing it's value but as it is a hidden field, yes of course you need to use document.getElementById there

Comment: Thanks! I got it to show the values on the other page, much appreciated. Last question.. how then, do I get it to update that value that's in the session if they change the selection from the dropdown?

Comment: The same way as you set the session. Take the selected value from dropdown using javascript and then set/update it